# Upload and read text/csv file in java

Tags: java, rest, file, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am new to file handling. I want to read the uploaded text or CSV file.
The controller loooks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/{testid}/consumers")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Subscription createConsumer(@PathVariable String cid, @FormParam("file") InputStream inputStream)
```

And I am reading this in service like this:

```
public Subscription createSubscription(String campaingid, InputStream file) {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));

        log.debug("Write File--------------------------- ");
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            log.debug("Line: " + line);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("Exception while reading input " + ioe);
        } 
}
```

But I am getting null value in 'br' object. What is wrong I am doing here? I am not using jersey framework. I am using spring boot rest.

Comment: Check if input stream is not empty.

Comment: @JaspreetJolly No it's not

Comment: Try getting this value fileInputStream.available(). If it is 0 then please check your file content as your createSubscription() method code is fine.It is working fine on my system.

Comment: @JaspreetJolly Yes it's 0. But I tried with other simple text file for it also I am getting 0 value. Is anything wrong I am doing? For testing purpose, I am uploading a file in postman in the body section using key as a file and value as actual text file

Comment: Sorry, but your information is incorrect. From the code above `br` cannot `== null`. Something else may be null or empty, but `br` is either assigned, or there is an exception during assignment. Or you are leaving a part of code out, which sets `br` to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for this !
I modify it as follows:

```
@PostMapping("/{testid}/consumers")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Subscription createConsumer(@PathVariable String cid, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
```

And I am reading it as follows:

```
InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> mList = CommonCSVParser.getMapFromCSV(reapExcelDataFile);

@Autowired
    SUBDetailsValyuStagingRepo sUBDetailsValyuStagingRepo;

        System.out.println("----- CSVDisbursmentFileImport ===");

        String Client = "";
        String ValyuApplicationId = "";// new
        String LenderLoanId = "";// new
        String EmpId = "";
        String BorrowerFirstName = "";
        String BorrowerLastName = "";
        String PhoneNumber = "";
        String DateOfBirth = "";
        String MaritalStatus = "";
        String Gender = "";
        String AddressLine1 = "";
        String AddressLine2 = "";
        String AddressCity = "";
        String AddressState = "";
        String AddressPinCode = "";
        String PanNumber = "";
        String AadhhaarNumber = "";
        String LoanAgreemenCopy = "";
        String SalaryConsentCopy = ""; // new
        String KycReportCopy = "";
        String DataDocCopy = "";
        String PanCardCopy = "";
        String AadhaarCardCopy = "";
        String Selfie = "";
        String EmployerName = "";
        String DateOfJoining = "";
        String EmployementType = "";
        String EmployementStatus = "";
        String Designation = "";
        String SalaryPayoutDate = "";
        Double GrossSalary = 0.0;
        Double NetSalary = 0.0;
        String BankAccountName = "";
        String BankName = "";
        String IfscCode = "";
        String BankAccountNumber = "";
        Double Eligibility = 0.0;
        String EligibilityPercentage = "";
        String DisbursementTranche = "";
        String AvailableLimit = "";
        String SubscriptionFee = "";
        String Gst = "";
        String LenderLoanAmount = "";
        String SettlementAmount = "";
        String RepaymentDate = "";
        String DisbursementDate = "";

        ActivationStaging ActivationStaging;

        List<ActivationStaging> ActivationStagingList = new ArrayList<ActivationStaging>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {

            try {

                ActivationStaging = new ActivationStaging();

                for (Entry<String, Object> entry : mList.get(i).entrySet()) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(entry);

                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[0].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[0])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                Client = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                                System.out.println("----- Client ---- " + Client);
                            }

                            /*
                             * if (Date != null && Date != "") {
                             * String DateOfTxnformateedSt = DateUtlis.getYYYYMMDDFromddMMMYYYY(Date);
                             * 
                             * SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss");
                             * 
                             * Date = fmtOut.parse(DateOfTxnformateedSt);
                             * 
                             * System.out.println("----- DateOfTxnSt ---- " + DateOfTxnSt);
                             * }
                             */

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[1].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[1])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                ValyuApplicationId = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- ValyuApplicationId ---- " + ValyuApplicationId);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[2].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[2])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                LenderLoanId = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- LenderLoanId ---- " + LenderLoanId);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[3].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[3])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                EmpId = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- EmpId ---- " + EmpId);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[4].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[4])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                BorrowerFirstName = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- BorrowerFirstName ---- " + BorrowerFirstName);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[5].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[5])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                BorrowerLastName = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- BorrowerLastName ---- " + BorrowerLastName);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[6].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[6])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                PhoneNumber = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- PhoneNumber ---- " + PhoneNumber);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[7].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[7])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                DateOfBirth = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- DateOfBirth ---- " + DateOfBirth);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[8].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[8])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                MaritalStatus = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- MaritalStatus ---- " + MaritalStatus);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[9].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[9])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                Gender = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- Gender ---- " + Gender);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[10].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[10])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                AddressLine1 = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- AddressLine1 ---- " + AddressLine1);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[11].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[11])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                AddressLine2 = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- AddressLine2 ---- " + AddressLine2);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[12].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[12])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                AddressCity = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- AddressCity ---- " + AddressCity);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[13].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[13])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                AddressState = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- AddressState ---- " + AddressState);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[14].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[14])) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                                AddressPinCode = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- AddressPinCode ---- " + AddressPinCode);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[15].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[15].toLowerCase())) {
                                PanNumber = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }

                            System.out.println("----- PanNumber ---- " + PanNumber);
                        }

                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[16].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[16])) {
                                AadhhaarNumber = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- AadhhaarNumber ---- " + AadhhaarNumber);

                        }

                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[17].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[17])) {

                                LoanAgreemenCopy = entry.getValue().toString().trim();

                            }
                            System.out.println("----- LoanAgreemenCopy ---- " + LoanAgreemenCopy);
                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[18].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[18])) {
                                SalaryConsentCopy = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- SalaryConsentCopy ---- " + SalaryConsentCopy);

                        }

                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[19].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[19])) {
                                KycReportCopy = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- KycReportCopy ---- " + KycReportCopy);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[20].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[20])) {
                                DataDocCopy = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- DataDocCopy ---- " + DataDocCopy);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[21].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[21])) {
                                PanCardCopy = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- PanCardCopy ---- " + PanCardCopy);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[22].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[22])) {
                                AadhaarCardCopy = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- AadhaarCardCopy ---- " + AadhaarCardCopy);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[23].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[23])) {
                                Selfie = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- Selfie ---- " + Selfie);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[24].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[24])) {
                                EmployerName = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- EmployerName ---- " + EmployerName);

                        }

                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[25].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[25])) {
                                DateOfJoining = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- DateOfJoining ---- " + DateOfJoining);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[26].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[26])) {
                                EmployementType = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- EmployementType ---- " + EmployementType);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[27].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[27])) {
                                EmployementStatus = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- EmployementStatus ---- " + EmployementStatus);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[28].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[28])) {
                                Designation = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- Designation ---- " + Designation);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[29].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[29])) {
                                SalaryPayoutDate = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- SalaryPayoutDate ---- " + SalaryPayoutDate);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[30].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[30])) {
                                GrossSalary = Double.parseDouble(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- GrossSalary ---- " + GrossSalary);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[31].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[31])) {
                                NetSalary = Double.parseDouble(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- NetSalary ---- " + NetSalary);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[32].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[32])) {
                                BankAccountName = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- BankAccountName ---- " + BankAccountName);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[33].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[33])) {
                                BankName = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- BankName ---- " + BankName);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[34].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[34])) {
                                IfscCode = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- IfscCode ---- " + IfscCode);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[35].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[35])) {
                                BankAccountNumber = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- BankAccountNumber ---- " + BankAccountNumber);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[36].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[36])) {
                                Eligibility = Double.parseDouble(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- Eligibility ---- " + Eligibility);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[37].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[37])) {
                                EligibilityPercentage = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- EligibilityPercentage ---- " + EligibilityPercentage);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[38].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[38])) {
                                DisbursementTranche = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- DisbursementTranche ---- " + DisbursementTranche);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[39].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[39])) {
                                AvailableLimit = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- AvailableLimit ---- " + AvailableLimit);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[40].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[40])) {
                                SubscriptionFee = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- SubscriptionFee ---- " + SubscriptionFee);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[41].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[41])) {
                                Gst = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- Gst ---- " + Gst);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[42].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[42])) {
                                LenderLoanAmount = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- LenderLoanAmount ---- " + LenderLoanAmount);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[43].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[43])) {
                                SettlementAmount = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- SettlementAmount ---- " + SettlementAmount);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[44].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[44])) {
                                RepaymentDate = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- RepaymentDate ---- " + RepaymentDate);

                        }
                        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(Keys[45].toLowerCase())) {

                            if (entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Keys[45])) {
                                DisbursementDate = entry.getValue().toString().trim();
                            }
                            System.out.println("----- DisbursementDate ---- " + DisbursementDate);

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                // ----------------------------------------- Save data to table
                // ---------------------------------------------------------//

                ActivationStaging.setClient(Client);
                ActivationStaging.setValyu_application_id(ValyuApplicationId);
                ActivationStaging.setLender_loan_id(LenderLoanId);
                ActivationStaging.setEmp_id(EmpId);
                ActivationStaging.setBorrower_first_name(BorrowerFirstName);
                ActivationStaging.setBorrower_last_name(BorrowerLastName);
                ActivationStaging.setPhone_number(PhoneNumber);
                ActivationStaging.setDate_of_birth(DateOfBirth);
                ActivationStaging.setMarital_status(MaritalStatus);
                ActivationStaging.setGender(Gender);
                ;
                ActivationStaging.setAddress_line1(AddressLine1);
                ActivationStaging.setAddress_line2(AddressLine2);
                ActivationStaging.setAddress_city(AddressCity);
                ActivationStaging.setAddress_state(AddressState);
                ActivationStaging.setAddress_pin_code(AddressPinCode);
                ActivationStaging.setPan_number(PanNumber);
                ActivationStaging.setAadhhaar_number(AadhhaarNumber);
                ActivationStaging.setLoan_agreement_copy(LoanAgreemenCopy);
                ActivationStaging.setSalary_consent_copy(SalaryConsentCopy);
                ActivationStaging.setKyc_report_copy(KycReportCopy);
                ActivationStaging.setData_doc_copy(DataDocCopy);
                ActivationStaging.setPan_card_copy(PanCardCopy);
                ActivationStaging.setAadhaar_card_copy(AadhaarCardCopy);
                ActivationStaging.setSelfie(Selfie);
                ActivationStaging.setEmployer_name(EmployerName);
                ActivationStaging.setDate_of_joining(DateOfJoining);
                ActivationStaging.setEmployement_type(EmployementType);
                ActivationStaging.setEmployement_status(EmployementStatus);
                ActivationStaging.setDesignation(Designation);
                ActivationStaging.setSalary_payout_date(SalaryPayoutDate);
                ActivationStaging.setGross_salary(GrossSalary);
                ActivationStaging.setNet_salary(NetSalary);
                ActivationStaging.setBank_account_name(BankAccountName);
                ActivationStaging.setBank_name(BankName);
                ActivationStaging.setIfsc_code(IfscCode);
                ActivationStaging.setBank_account_number(BankAccountNumber);
                ActivationStaging.setEligibility(Eligibility);
                ActivationStaging.setEligibility_percentage(EligibilityPercentage);
                ActivationStaging.setDisbursement_tranche(DisbursementTranche);
                ActivationStaging.setAvailable_limit(AvailableLimit);
                ActivationStaging.setSubscription_fee(SubscriptionFee);
                ActivationStaging.setGst(Gst);
                ActivationStaging.setLender_loan_amount(LenderLoanAmount);
                ActivationStaging.setSettlement_amount(SettlementAmount);
                ActivationStaging.setRepayment_date(RepaymentDate);
                ActivationStaging.setDisbursement_date(DisbursementDate);

                ActivationStaging.setIs_processed(PROCESSING);
                ActivationStaging.setRemarks(MobikwikConstantData.TEXT_PROCESS);
                ActivationStaging.setCreated_by(mPartner.getUid());
                ActivationStaging.setUpdated_by(mPartner.getUid());
                ActivationStaging.setUpated_date(new Date());

                // Add data to list//
                ActivationStagingList.add(ActivationStaging);
                sUBDetailsValyuStagingRepo.save(ActivationStaging);
                // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
//-----------------------------------------------------//

public class CommonCSVParser {

    // ------------------------------------------//
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> getMapFromCSV(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        try {
            CSVParser parser = parseCSV(multipartFile.getInputStream());
            return getMap(parser.getRecords(), parser.getHeaderMap());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static List<Map<String, Object>> getMap(List<CSVRecord> records, Map<String, Integer> headers) {
        Map<Integer, String> headerMap = formatHeaderMap(headers);
        List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                CSVRecord record = records.get(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < record.size(); j++) {
                    map.put(headerMap.get(j), record.get(j));
                }
                data.add(map);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    private static Map<Integer, String> formatHeaderMap(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        Map<Integer, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        map.forEach((k, v) -> {
            data.put(v, k);
        });
        return data;
    }

    private static CSVParser parseCSV(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            return new CSVParser(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                    .withIgnoreHeaderCase().withSkipHeaderRecord().withTrim());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface SUBDetailsValyuStagingRepo extends CrudRepository<ActivationStaging, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE valyu_user_activation_staging SET is_processed=:is_processed,remarks=:remarks  WHERE lender_cif_id=:lender_cif_id", nativeQuery = true)

    @Transactional
    void updateIsProccess(@Param("lender_cif_id") long lender_cif_id, @Param("is_processed") int is_processed,
            @Param("remarks") String remarks);

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "activation_staging")
public class ActivationStaging {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long lender_cif_id;

    String client;
    // String product_type;
    String valyu_application_id;// new
    String lender_loan_id;// new
    String emp_id;
    String borrower_first_name;
    String borrower_last_name;
    String phone_number;
    String date_of_birth;
    String marital_status;
    String gender;
    String address_line1;
    String address_line2;
    String address_city;
    String address_state;
    String address_pin_code;
    String pan_number;
    String aadhhaar_number;
    String loan_agreement_copy;
    String salary_consent_copy;// new
    String kyc_report_copy;
    String data_doc_copy;
    String pan_card_copy;
    String aadhaar_card_copy;
    String selfie;
    String employer_name;
    String date_of_joining;
    String employement_type;
    String employement_status;
    String designation;
    String salary_payout_date;
    Double gross_salary;
    Double net_salary;
    String bank_account_name;
    String bank_name;
    String Ifsc_code;
    String bank_account_number;
    Double eligibility;
    String eligibility_percentage;
    String disbursement_tranche;
    String available_limit;
    String subscription_fee;
    String gst;
    String lender_loan_amount;
    String settlement_amount;
    String repayment_date;
    String disbursement_date;
    long created_by;
    long updated_by;
    Date created_date = new Date();
    Date upated_date;
    int is_processed = 1; // PROCESSING=1 / COMPLETE =2
    String remarks;
}
```